# Using AWS Cognito UserID as partition key in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am creating an application. The users can register and log in via AWS Cognito and MFA SMS Verification.

The specific user information, created in the app, will be stored in a DynamoDB table.

My idea is to use the UserID from Cognito as the Partition Key (user_ID) in DynamoDB.
My first thought is to use a Lambda function that is triggered when a user successfully registered in my app, and creates a User item in DynamoDB with the Cognito UserID as Partition Key (user_ID).

Does this make sense or is there a best practice how to set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this makes sense and is what most people use for Cognito as it allows you to use DynamoDB's [fine grained access control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html), meaning users logging in can only access information belonging to them in your DynamoDB table, offering an extra layer of security.